# How to translate "bug tracker" or "issue tracker"?

Tags: single-word-requests, information-technology

In modern software development, it's customary and considered a best practice to keep track of open tasks and/or known bugs. This is usually done with specialized software: a [bug tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_tracking_system) (a.k.a. bug tracking system or defect tracking system) or more generally an [issue tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking_system) (a.k.a. issue tracking system). (Often the term "bug tracker" is used in English, even if the tracked issues aren't limited to bugs, but may also be feature requests, open refactoring tasks or even open questions, etc.)

**What would be a good Esperanto term for that kind of tool?**

Komputeko [comes up with](https://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=tracking) *"cimspuradilo"* and *"problem-spurado"*, but I have the impression that *"spuri"* is a too verbatim translation of a somewhat different meaning of "to track", i.e., actually following a physical track, rather than *keeping track of* (i.e. to *manage*) items on a versatile ToDo list.

Comment: Interestingly, PIV's [definition](http://vortaro.net/#spurilo) of _spurilo_ refers to _spuri_, and the IT one of the two meanings given there seems to indicate that this is about [debuggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) (which are a type of software quite different from bug trackers): _Sekvi la plenumadon de komputila programo paŝon post paŝo por trovi misfunkcion._

Comment: How about something like cimĵurnalo?

Comment: Can you make an answer from that suggestion, @Olafant? Using a kunmeto based on _ĵurnalo_ (with the 3rd meaning [from PIV](http://vortaro.net/#%C4%B5urnalo) _en komerco: Libro, en kiu estas registrataj kronologie, tagon post tago, ĉiuj kont-operacioj de firmo, entrepreno ks._) seems promising to me.

Answer (score 1):

*Erarraportoj* is the translation I found [for Mozilla](https://transvision.mozfr.org/string/?entity=browser/profile/bookmarks.inc:bugzilla&repo=gecko_strings). The link points to all the supported locales. It's interesting to see how the other languages solve the same thing.

I suggest *Erarraporta sistemo* or *Sistemo de raporto de eraroj*.

Comment: I guess _erarraportoj_ just means "bug reports". So _erarraportilo_ or _erarraportujo_ could work.

Answer (score 1):

I think, sometimes it's better to find a word based on the meaning instead of translating terms that are 
already not really clear in other languages. For *keeping track of something*, you could use

> ĵurnalo

for example. [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#%C4%B5urnalo) lists one of its meanings as

> Libro, en kiu estas registrataj kronologie, tagon post tago, ĉiuj kont-operacioj de firmo, entrepreno ks.

If you want to keep track of bugs, it could be called

> cimĵurnalo

and if you want to keep track of updates you could call it something like

> ĝisdatigĵurnalo

and so on.

Comment: I think _ĵurnalo_ is so heavily associated with _ĉiutaga gazeto_

Answer (score 0):

According to PIV the basic word is a noun, [*spuro*](http://vortaro.net/#spuro), for which there are four definitions. Of these two are from mathematics and not of interest here, one says *spuro estas evitinda sama kiel ŝpuro*. For the remaining one are given examples, which more or less indicate verbatim interpretation, like you put it. However if you take a look little below, there is word *elspurado* with examples, which suggest that the word can also be used figuratively.

Komputeko gives for tracker two words: *sekvilo* and *spurilo*. For me the difference is, that *sekvilo* is a tool to keep book of something known (Komputeko: exepense tracker = *sekvilo de elspezoj*), while *spurilo* is more general.

The English word "issue" is easily used in a euphemistic manner instead of the word "problem". However I agree with Komputeko here, that issue tracking is *problem-spurado* and thus the tool is *problem-spurilo*.

See the word "track" in [Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/index_en.php?vorto=track).

Comment: Hmm ... the main task of a bug tracker _is_ bookkeeping: _What bugs are known? What is known about the respective bug? Has it been fixed? Who's responsible for investigating or fixing it?_ Would that mean that _sekvilo_ would be more fitting than _spurilo_?

Comment: One of the reasons why I'm wary of just using what Komputeko suggests is that even in IT, "to track" (and by extension "tracking" and "tracker") are used for various mutually very different processes, especially also for recording actual ways in space (e.g. GPS traces recorded by a GPS tracker), which feels very different from the "keeping track of" meaning (the bookkeeping).

Comment: This is how I understand. An expense is more or less known in advance and more importantly tracked up a long time (what fiscal requirements say, but years anyway), thus _sekvilo de elspezoj_. A bug, an issue is hopefully not known in advance (we all do want bug-free software), and surely is closed when the issue has been solved, _problem-spurilo_.

Comment: @das-g, there is no 1:1 relationship between any two languages, especially English is notorious for having words with multiple meanings. So there is not a single word in _la espa_, that means "tracking" in its various contexts in English (expense, issue, GPS… tracking). Wikipedia uses the verb _biri_ with GPS, PIV defines [_biri_](http://vortaro.net/#biri) as "Precizigi la pozicion de punkto en la spaco…", so GPS device is _birilo_ and the definition already gives us the verb, to track = _precizigi_.

Comment: I'm not looking for a general translation of "tracking", as I'm well aware no word to cover all meanings of it (and exactly only those meanings) would exist in other languages. But exactly because the word has several meanings, I'm a bit afraid that Esperanto terms suggested so far might be based on too verbatim translations of the English term(s). (One could argue that "bug tracker" and "issue tracker" are already unfortunately confusingly named in English and that an Esperanto term should, if possible, be more descriptive of what such a  tool actually does.)

Comment: Ok, based on my native language (not English) I would call the action "to follow" or "to track". The Lernu dictionary gives: _sekvi, postiri, postsekvi, sukcedi, postveni, laŭiri_ and _spuri_. Note, that _spuri_ has a computer-related meaning according to [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#spuri): "Sekvi la plenumadon de komputila programo paŝon post paŝo por trovi misfunkcion", i.e. to debug. So I incline to _sekvilo_ and _spurilo_ with the nuance difference I wrote about above. BTW an issue could be translated to _afero_, so if _problem-spurilo_ sounds to harsh, perhaps _aferospurilo_ would do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101176/discussion-between-das-g-and-juha-metsakallas).